# use sec.axis from ggplot2 in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am using `ggplotly` to make plotly graphs and have been using sec.axis to label my facets in ggplot2. Like this:
[image: ggplot]

After this I try to pass the ggplot object to `ggplotly` and the sec.axis disappears. I tried to add a second yaxis in `layout()` but it does not seem to work. How can I label my facets in `plotly` similar to using `sec.axis()` in `ggplot2`?

```
library(ggplot2)

library(plotly)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars)+
      geom_point(aes(x = cyl , y = mpg))+
      facet_grid(vs~am)+
      scale_y_continuous("MPG", sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "VS") )+ 
      theme(strip.placement = "outside")

ay <- list(
  tickfont = list(size=11.7),
  titlefont=list(size=14.6),
  overlaying = "y",
  nticks = 5,
  side = "right",
  title = list(
  text = "Second y axis",
  standoff = 0)
)

ggplotly(p1) %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = ay)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible at this time, but maybe in the future? For more info:

- https://plotly.com/ggplot2/Guides%20axes%20and%20legends/sec_axis/
- https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1051

Comment: thank you for this, I will keep an eye out on the github page for more updates!